# Karma Test With angular 6

Tags: angular, npm, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I am tring to run test of angular using npm

`ng test`

but the problem is that chrome start and not stop after test finish so I used :

```
ng test --watch=false
```

but that cause error "Chrome 69.0.3497 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR"
which make chrome timeout
I am trying to run that on continuous deployment server so this error cause fail in the process any idea how to stop that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can avoid this under unix based system using the [Headless chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

> It's a way to run the Chrome browser in a headless environment. Essentially, running Chrome without chrome! It brings all modern web platform features provided by Chromium and the Blink rendering engine to the command line.

**first:**
configure your `karma.conf.js` to use headless chrome e.g adding a `customLaunchers`:

```
...
browsers: ['Chrome'],
customLaunchers: {
    ChromeNoSandboxHeadless: {
       base: 'ChromeHeadless',
       flags: ['--no-sandbox']
    }
 },
```

**second:** 
tell your `package.json` script to use your config for testing:

```
"scripts": {
   ...
    "test": "ng test --browsers=ChromeNoSandboxHeadless",
   ...
  },
```

then run `npm run test` or `yarn test` and your tests will works without open your browser. You can open the displayed `url` in your prefered browsers(firefox, chrome, chromium etc...).

**second way:**
You can display all your test cases in your console using [Karma-mocha-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-mocha-reporter)

- First : install `npm install karma-mocha-reporter --save-dev`
- Second: require your reporter inside `karma.conf.js` under `plugins` like `require('karma-mocha-reporter'),`

Then add the new reporter `mocha` to your reporters array: `reporters: ['mocha', 'progress', 'kjhtml']`

Run your test using `npm run test` or `yarn test` will display the report into your console.

**another way:**

in your `karma.config.json` take a look at the option `singleRun` (a boolean default set to `false`). Set `true`, Karma will start and capture all configured browsers, run tests and then exit with an exit code of 0 or 1 depending on whether all tests passed or any tests failed. Alternativ, run it using the flag `npm run test --single-run`.

Answer (score 2):

In your `karma.conf.js`, change `singleRun` to `true`.

```
singleRun: true
```

Comment: I don't have that file

Comment: Did you check the same folder as your package.json?