# Cannot start ChromeHeadless in Angular project using WSL, works on Mac

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux (Windows 10, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). I'll list all the other pertinent versions below.

This setup is working on my Mac machine, without the `flags` array added to `karma.conf.ts` as shown below.

So far I've looked at:

[Headless Chrome slows tests by 10x](https://github.com/Codeception/CodeceptJS/issues/561#issuecomment-373666779)

[Ubuntu: Cannot start ChromeHeadless](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/175)

[Google Chrome 75.0.3770.80 HEADLESS no longer works inside Docker container](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/198)

["rebuilding" yarn using `npm rebuild --update-binary`](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2069)

[Karma Test With angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700343/karma-test-with-angular-6)

**Expected Behaviour**
To launch ChromeHeadless and run the tests

**Current Behaviour**
Running `yarn test` as I would normally results in this error:

```
02 10 2019 09:13:03.598:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stdout:
02 10 2019 09:13:03.608:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stderr: Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Permission denied
Failed to generate minidump.
02 10 2019 09:13:03.623:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir /tmp/karma-5419534
 21% building 99/100 modules 1 active ...ngenio/packages/web-app/src/styles.scss02 10 2019 09:13:03.699:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start ChromeHeadless again (2/2).
02 10 2019 09:13:03.702:DEBUG [launcher]: BEING_CAPTURED -> RESTARTING
02 10 2019 09:13:03.715:DEBUG [launcher]: RESTARTING -> FINISHED
 22% building 100/101 modules 1 active ...project/packages/web-app/src/styles.scss02 10 2019 09:13:03.801:DEBUG [launcher]: Restarting ChromeHeadless
02 10 2019 09:13:03.803:DEBUG [launcher]: FINISHED -> BEING_CAPTURED
02 10 2019 09:13:03.804:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at /tmp/karma-5419534
02 10 2019 09:13:03.814:DEBUG [launcher]: google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/karma-5419534 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-device-discovery-notifications http://localhost:9876/?id=5419534 --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222
 27% building 144/145 modules 1 active ...project/packages/web-app/src/styles.scss02 10 2019 09:13:05.142:DEBUG [launcher]: Process ChromeHeadless exited with code null and signal SIGILL
02 10 2019 09:13:05.147:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start ChromeHeadless
        Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Permission denied
Failed to generate minidump.
02 10 2019 09:13:05.159:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stdout:
02 10 2019 09:13:05.171:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stderr: Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Permission denied
Failed to generate minidump.
02 10 2019 09:13:05.187:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir /tmp/karma-5419534
 34% building 205/206 modules 1 active ...project/packages/web-app/src/styles.scss02 10 2019 09:13:05.679:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.
02 10 2019 09:13:05.680:DEBUG [launcher]: BEING_CAPTURED -> FINISHED
02 10 2019 09:13:13.587:DEBUG [karma-server]: List of files has changed, trying to execute
02 10 2019 09:13:13.588:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
```

and after `ctrl+c`...

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot destructure property `error` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
See "/tmp/ng-GhKvib/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The file `/tmp/ng-GhKvib/angular-errors.log` contains `An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot destructure property`error`of 'undefined' or 'null'.`.

**Karma Config**

```
// karma.conf.ts

module.exports = (config) => {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false,
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/ng2angle'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 10000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
    flags: [
      '--disable-web-security',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-features=NetworkService',
      '--proxy-server="direct://"',
      '--proxy-bypass-list=*',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
    ],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
  });
};
```

The command that `yarn test` runs is `ng test --karmaConfig=karma.conf.ts`.

**Versions**

```
yarn=1.19.0
angular-cli=8.3.2
karma=4.1.0
karma-chrome-launcher=2.2.0
tsc=2.7.2
```

### Edit

Eventually I just gave up on using Linux for this and am using Mac. Watch my [issue in the `karma-chrome-launcher` repo](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/214) for possible fixes in the future.

Comment: this is a known problem. there are plenty of other issues/incidents about that. unfortunately there is no solution for that yet.

Answer (score 11):

To make this run successfully, Please follow the procedure

Method 1: **Most of the issues will be fixed and we can run ChromeHeadless if we download chromium version(debian) in wsl and install**

step 1: install necessary packages

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y curl unzip xvfb libxi6 libgconf-2-4
```

step 2: install chromium

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

*If still problem persists, please follow the method 2*

**method 2: To run a basic Selenium UI test on any environment we need a browser and a driver to control the browser. So we've to make Windows’s Chrome browser and the chromedriver accessible from WSL.**

step 1: Link Chrome browser on Windows

```
sudo ln -sf '/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe' /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

step 2: Link chromedriver on Windows

```
sudo ln -s /mnt/c/Users/username/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

step 3: Change CHROME_BIN (environmental variable's default value)

```
export CHROME_BIN='/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
```

*If still problem persists, please follow the method 3*

**Method 3: This will help run puppetteer on Ubuntu, so let's install necessary packages:**

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

- [See my GitHub solution link](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/214#issuecomment-828505074)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/175#issuecomment-828511363)

Comment: `Chrome stderr: [7525:7525:0507/105416.886818:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1386)] Unable to open X display.`

Comment: @PaoloStefan Are you using cloud IDE such as `cloud9` or `codeanywhere` ?

Comment: @PaoloStefan in this case, please configure `puppeteer` in your framework as below(do with all the possible options)

    puppeteerLaunchOptions: {
          args: [
            "--disable-gpu",
            "--renderer",
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--no-service-autorun",
            "--no-experiments",
            "--no-default-browser-check",
            "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
            "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
            "--no-first-run",
            "--no-zygote",
            "--single-process",
            "--disable-extensions"
          ]
        }

Comment: no, I'm using plain WSL, on a Windows machine.

Comment: This workaround is working perfectly at WSL1. Could you please check yours?

Comment: this works for WSL 2.0 also, I had to follow steps 1 + 3 to get puppetteer and chromeheadless happy. Thank you!

Comment: I think I'm in the same boat as x0n but I did step 2 in between and now it's looking in the wrong place for chrome 
(Cannot start Chrome
        Can not find the binary /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
        Please set env variable CHROME_BIN)
How do I undo the environment variable change?